# How should I create this index?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, indexing, sql-server-2012

I have queries that look like:

```
select blah, foo
from tableA
where makedate = @somedate

select bar, baz
from tableA
where vendorid = @someid

select foobar, onetwo
from tableA
where vendorid = @someid and makedate between @date1 and @date2
```

Should I create just one index:

```
create nonclustered index searches_index on tableA(vendorid, makedate)
```

Should I create 3 indexes:

```
 create nonclustered index searches_index on tableA(vendorid,
   makedate)

 create nonclustered index searches_index on tableA(vendorid)

 create nonclustered index searches_index on tableA(makedate)
```

Also are these two different indexes? In other words, does column order matter?

```
create nonclustered index searches_index on tableA(vendorid, makedate)

create nonclustered index searches_index on tableA(makedate, vendorid)
```

I've been reading up on indexes but not sure on the best way to make them?

Comment: You should create the 3 indexes.

Comment: @GMastros - please see edit above

Comment: Yes those indexes with different order are different. And what is the PK of tableA.  You do know SSMS will recommend queries.  You really need to test with your data as it can depend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither of your suggestions is optimal.

You should create *two* indexes:

```
 create nonclustered index searches_index on tableA(vendorid, makedate)

 create nonclustered index searches_index on tableA(makedate)
```

The reasons is that the first index on (vendorid, makedate) will be used for both the second and third of your sample queries; an index on (vendorid) only would be redundant.

**[Edit]** To answer your additional question:

Yes, column order *does* matter in index creation.  An index on `(vendorid, makedate)` can be used to optimize queries of the form `WHERE vendorid = ? AND makedate = ?` or `WHERE vendorid = ?` but *cannot* help with the query `WHERE makedate = ?`.  In order to get any significant index optimization on the last query you would need an index with `makedate` at the *head* of the index.  (Note that in my example queries "=" means *any optimizable condition*).

There exist some edge cases in which an otherwise unhelpful index (like `(vendorid, makedate)` in a query against `makedate` only) can provide some nominal help in returning data as @Bram points out in the comments.  For instance, if you return only the columns `makedate` and `vendorid` in that query then the SQL engine can treat the index as a mini-table and sequentially scan that to find the matching rows, never having to look at the full copy of the table.  This is called a *covering index*.

Comment: The assumption is that vendorid is the primary key and that would make it redundant? Also now you have me wondering if the order of the columns count. I'll add that to my post above.

Comment: Yes, the order of the columns count when determining whether a single multi-column index can be used to optimize two or more terms in the WHERE clause.  For this to be possible, the terms must contain optimizable expressions referring to the *head columns* of the index.

Comment: The `vendorid` column cannot, in and of itself, be the primary key for this table; that would allow only a single record per vendor and you would never finding yourself looking up based on date as well.  Therefore, the primary key would be *at minimum* (vendorid, makedate).  If this is true, there is *already* an index on these columns so *do not* create a second index -- more overhead for zero gain.

Comment: It seems my question was badly worded. I was trying to understand why an index on vendorid would be redundant but an index on makedate wouldn't be.

Comment: Agree with this answer (and upvoted), but might make a small amendment. Possible value in an INCLUDE statement for each index. Can't really tell from the details given as we don't know the full structure of the table, or column types.

Comment: Sorry got to take away the up vote.  If there are no other indexes a search on makedate might use on index (vendorid, makedate).

Comment: Blam: Vote as you see fit, but your statement is wrong.  An index on `(vendorid, makedate)` will *never* be used in a query that does not have an optimizable filter condition on `vendorid`.  Never.  Ever.

Comment: I am looking at one right now.  So if you want to post that as a question I will answer.

Comment: Is it a covering index for the query?

Comment: If you want to post that as a question I will answer.  I know what I am looking at.

Comment: @Blam a search on makedate could potentially use (VendorId, Makedate) index but it won't be doing an index seek it can only do an index scan. Take a look at myth 3 in http://www.sqlconsulting.com/news1012.htm

Comment: @SteveFord Exactly.  And the statement "An index on (vendorid, makedate) will never be used in a query that does not have an optimizable filter condition on vendorid. Never. Ever." is wrong.

Comment: @Blam: You're correct, that performing an index scan, although a trivial optimization, technically "uses the index" (even though it's not using the index *as an index* but rather as the source of a sequential scan).  I'll modify my answer to reflect this.

Comment: @LarryLustig Cheers. In my book scanning an index is using an index.  I am not even going to go into trivial with you.

Answer (score 0):

If it were me, and I knew that the table was always going to be queried in one of those three ways you listed, I would create three indexes as you suggested.  Those are pretty light-weight indexes to have, so I wouldn't be concerned (generally speaking) about the other costs that multiple indexes will incur.

Just my opinion, I'm sure there are others contrary.

Also side note: when creating 3 indexes, they will all need to have a unique name